# Clarification in proof related to monomials as basis for polynomial space

Tags: polynomials

I have seen a proof that the set $\{1,  x,  ...  ,  x^{n-1}\}$ form a basis for $P_{n}(x)$ as given below:

To show  that  $\{1,  x,  ...  ,  x^{n-1}\}$  is a basis for $P_{n}(x)$, let  $a_{0},a_{1},  ...  ,a_{n-1}$  be
scalars  such  that $a_{0} + a_{1}x + ... + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} = 0$. Now   setting  $x  = 0$
yields  $a_{0} = 0$.

I have a doubt in the following claim:

*In  a similar way by factoring  $x$  each time,  we  see
that  $a_{0}=a_{1}=  ...  =a_{n-1} = 0$.*

Consider  $a_{1}x + ... + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} = 0$,

$x(a_{1} + ... + a_{n-1}x^{n-2}) = 0$.

I cannot set $x  = 0$ here right. Then how to prove $a_{1} = 0$.

I just want to know whether the claim is right or wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prove? That the set $\{1,x,...,x^{n-1}\}$ is linearly independent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you obtain a product of two polynomials, and you know that the polynomial x is not the zero polynomial. That means the polynomial in parantheses must be the zero polynomial (if $pq=0$, then at least one of $p,q$ must be zero). Rinse and repeat.